# What is the safest gpu/cpu temp to run in all day?

Tags: gpu, cpu-usage, cpu-cooler

I have a gtx 1050 ti oc dual fan and an i3 4160 i usr both of them for mining all day 24/7. gpu average is 68c and 77c is the highest temp it reached And the cpu is running ay 53c.
So are these temps safe for all day usage?

Comment: Yes, you should worry only if they are being thermally throttled, but only because they are being thermally throttled

Comment: CPU temp seems like it's not at 100% usage (or you have really good cooling system), so it's ok. GPU temps are allright if you actually use it especially if it's overclocked. GPU temps at rest, when you've just booted the PC, should be around (even inferior) 40°C and the GPU fans should not spin.